# Google play promo video showed for a day, now it is not showing. Why?

Tags: android, video, google-play-console

As per some suggestions from another stack-overflow post I have used full link of the video in Google Play Main Store Listing

Also in YouTube video is not restricted https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6KDA.png

Visibility is Public in YouTube https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDCs8.png

Is there something I am missing or anything wrong with the video. Because it showed for a day but now it doesn't show. I checked this from some of the family members device too video is not showing in google play not from browser or mobile?

YouTube Promo Link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jibO8kE3bf4 
Google Play Link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devinspo.medi_nest
I saw some documentation and YouTube video they also did the same.